# can you decorate imperial levels to unlock the level

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

to unlock the level decorating you have to decorate 60 levels I have 55 regular levels and 10 imperial levels can I decorate imperial levels to get the level

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can.

Hmmm... I need to have at least 30 characters in a reply. Ok that should more than do it, I guess. :)

[image: Imperial Level]